# Code Comparison software

Tags: php, comparison

I have two directories with hundreds of PHP files in each. The second directory was copied from the first and worked on as a 'bad' way of version control. The issue is, we don't know which files were necessarily changed (the programmer did not provide any notes) and if they were, what was changed.

I have seen software which can compare the difference in two individually known text files but I am looking for something that can read all files in the directories (say PHP) and compare them.

Anybody know of something that might help?

### EDIT

I am currently running all my code on an XAMPP setup on a Windows XP machine.

Comment: @Mark Baker - good question, i'll add as an edit

Comment: Because of the ubiquity of Unix "diff", comparison tools like this are often generically known as "diff" utilities -- might give you a useful search term for Google...

Comment: Well, for Windows with two single directories, you can go proper old-school and try `fc dir1\\* dir2\\*` from the command line. It should still actually work, though it'll feel like you're stepping back into the 1980s :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use [Winmerge](http://winmerge.org/) in Windows. For Linux, there's a good [list](http://amjith.blogspot.com/2007/07/visual-diff-tools-in-linux.html) here

Comment: @Mark Baker - thanks for the help. I chose your answer because you gave a list for both OS

Comment: And there was me thinking I'd skipped Macs

Comment: well, i might have to go back on what I marked - WinMerge looks great but it forces me to select known files to find the differences. I am looking for something that shows me ALL files that have differences then if I select one or another, it will highlight 'what' is different in the two directories.

Comment: Point Winmerge to the directories, not to the individual files

Comment: @Mark Baker - then it seems it only analyzes whether files exist at all because several files that have known *major* differences are displayed as 'text files are identical'

Comment: I'll keep giving it a shot and see what I can find. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I've never had any problems with WinMerge, and enough others here have recommended it in their responses... check Edit/Options for details of the comparison rules

Answer (score 4):

i can absolutely an fully recommend BeyondCompare by Scootersoftware. 
IMHO it's the Photoshop of diff/merge tools.
http://scootersoftware.com/

You might also want to check here for other tools:
http://alternativeto.net/software/beyond-compare

Comment: I'll have to check out Beyond Compare. I really like the FTP comparison feature I saw on their site. Thank you for your help and the link as well

Comment: from what I can see so far in Beyond Compare, it still does not necessarily display the differences within directories (only folders or individual known files. Perhaps I need to play around with it more but I am also getting some very strange layout (where there are several blank spaces between files which mean nothing).

Comment: @MGiesbach, BeyondCompare wouldn't work for low-RAM computers.

Answer (score 3):

[WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) is a good open source solution for Windows - simply drop the two directories in one by one and it'll show you the modified files and you can drill-in and see the specific differences, etc.

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of ways to tackle this. At work, I use Beyond Compare, which does full directory and file comparison. There are others, including many you can download for free. For example, the windiff tool, which shipped with older versions of Visual Studio. It is not the most full featured, but it is an example.

Comment: You might want to have a quick read of [Are taglines & signatures disallowed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed/5038#5038) :-)

Answer (score 0):

Any decent diff tool should be able to compare directory trees as well as files. I rather like [meld](http://meld.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

What platform? Standard Unix "diff" will do this; just give it the two directories instead of individual files. On Windows, see if you can grab a copy of Windiff from somewhere; it comes with the standard Microsoft development tools, but I'm guessing you can find it as a standalone download from somewhere.

This earlier answer looks like it has a pretty definitive list of diff tools:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12625/best-diff-tool